# Ruby if else condition comparison

Tags: ruby

I have a question regarding the if else loops in Ruby. Here is the code

```
print "Enter your age: "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

print "Enter your sex(M/m/F/f) : "
sex = gets.upcase

if (sex == "M" and age > 21)
  puts "Hi dude. You may enter."
elsif(sex == "F" and age > 18)
  puts "Hi dudette. You may enter."
elsif (sex == "M" and age < 21)
  puts "Hi dude. You may not enter."
elsif(sex == "F" and age < 18)
  puts "Hi dudette. You may not enter."
else
  puts age
  puts sex
  puts "I do not recognize that sex. Enter only M, m, F, or f."
end
```

When I type in the inputs, regardless of what i enter it only enters into the else loop section. I've printed out the 2 variables age and sex to double check and they do fit the conditions I've listed. So is the problem here with my variables or is it my if else conditions?

Comment: The combinations `(M, 21)` and `(F, 18)` go to the else branch too. You should use `<=` or `>=` on one of the age tests for each sex.

Comment: @axiac Yup, i realized that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add the chomp to the sex part

```
print "Enter your age: "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

print "Enter your sex(M/m/F/f) : "
sex = gets.chomp.upcase

if (sex == "M" and age > 21)
  puts "Hi dude. You may enter."
elsif(sex == "F" and age > 18)
  puts "Hi dudette. You may enter."
elsif (sex == "M" and age < 21)
  puts "Hi dude. You may not enter."
elsif(sex == "F" and age < 18)
  puts "Hi dudette. You may not enter."
else
  puts age
  puts sex
  puts "I do not recognize that sex. Enter only M, m, F, or f."
end
```

This works

Comment: Oh, thank you! But can i ask if my understanding is correct? Because i missed out on chomp, does it mean i'm comparing for the variable sex's case "M\n" to "M"?

Comment: yes, exactly. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: Alright, done. Thanks again!

Comment: But it worked and I pointed out the mistake